# How can i filter Laravel models with pivot table in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I got two simple tables:
Users
Tasks
and additionally, I have pivot task_user with timestamps
How can I filter with Eloquent all users that were added to all tasks last month?

Comment: try `User::tasks()->wherePivot('created_at', '>', '2021-11-02');`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns